# Почему не работает регулярное выражение? Где ошибка?

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

мне нужно убрать два последних нуля в конце цифр в спане. Почему не работает этот код?

```
  <span class="currencySymbol">
 99.00
  </span><br>
  <span class="currencySymbol">
    3.300.00
     </span>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".currencySymbol").text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/.00$/, "")
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Потому что после двух ноликов стоят символы переноса строки и пробелы, существование которых вы забыли учесть в регулярке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`.currencySymbol`).forEach($item => {
  $item.innerHTML = $item.textContent.replace(/.00\s*$/, ``);
});
```

```html
<span class="currencySymbol">
 99.00
</span><br>
<span class="currencySymbol">
    3.300.00
</span>
```